# Каким образом можно вынести описание функции в отдельный файл?

Tags: c#

У меня есть длинные функции, которые, для удобства, хочется разместить в отдельных файлах.
Как правильно должен составляться такой файл? Насколько понимаю, требуется расширять класс Program или что-то в этом роде. Но как именно?

На всякий случай упомяну, что мне нужна, просто, функция, не связанная ни с какими классами.

Comment: У вас не должно быть таких желаний. Функции не должны быть длинными. Функция длиннее 50 строк подозрительна. Функция длиннее 100 строк ужасна. Функция длиннее 200 строк — преступление.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Согласен с [@DreamChild](/users/10162/dreamchild), что при нормальном написании кода потребности в таких странностях обычно не возникает, но если уж очень хочется, то можно использовать partial:

В одном файле:

```
public partial class TestApp
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(TestMethod());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

в другом:

```
public partial class TestApp
{
    public static string TestMethod()
    {
        return "!!!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> На всякий случай упомяну, что мне нужна, просто, функция, не связанная ни с какими классами

Такое в C# невозможно. Это полностью объектно-ориентированный язык, и функции (точнее, методы - в C# нет понятия "функция") могут находиться только в составе класса. Класс, впрочем, может быть статическим и по сути являться пространством имен для методов, однако методов без класса в шарпе быть не может.

Comment: Тогда как я могу написать метод класса Program в отдельном файле?

Comment: а зачем это нужно? При нормальном написании кода потребности в таких странностях обычно не возникает